# Event handlers on parent and child div

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling

Here is my HTML file

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.querySelector('.a').onclick = ()=>{
        document.querySelector('.a').style.backgroundColor ='black'
    }
    document.querySelector('.b').onclick = ()=>{
        document.querySelector('.b').style.backgroundColor ='violet'
    }

</script>
```

When I click on the div with class 'b' ,the event handler on the div with class 'a' is also called. I want only the div with 'b' class event handler to be called. Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Event Bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture), which means that each event is triggered not only on the target element but also on its ancestor elements.

To prevent this behavior, you can use [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop the event from propagating to the ancestor elements of the target element.

```js
document.querySelector('.a').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('.a').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
}

document.querySelector('.b').onclick = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  document.querySelector('.b').style.backgroundColor = 'violet'
}
```

```css
div { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.a { padding: 40px; background: red; }
.b { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
  a
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a concept called [Event Bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#bubbling) in JS. By default any event that's happening on a particular element will be propagated to the parent and to it's parent and so on till the event reaches the document.

In order to stop this behaviour [`Event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) will come to the rescue and will stop propagating the event to the parent.

So in this case calling `e.stopPropagation` in the `onclick` handler of the div with class `b` i.e., the inner div will stop the event to be propagated to the parent div.

```js
document.querySelector('.a').onclick = (e) => {
  document.querySelector('.a').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
}
document.querySelector('.b').onclick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  document.querySelector('.b').style.backgroundColor = 'violet'
}
```

```css
.b {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  Dummy
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
 document.querySelector('.a').onclick = ()=>{
        document.querySelector('.a').style.backgroundColor ='black'
    }
    document.querySelector('.b').onclick = (e) => {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        document.querySelector('.b').style.backgroundColor ='violet'
    }
```

```html
<div class="a">a
    <br/>
    <div class="b">
        Click here!
    </div>
</div>
```